# Prove that if $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. then $\phi_{X-Y}(t)=|\phi_{X}(t)|^2$.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Prove that if $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. then $\phi_{X-Y}(t)=|\phi_{X}(t)|^2$. So as $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. this implies that $\phi_X(t)=\phi_Y(t)$. Also, $$\phi_{X-Y}(t)=E[e^{it(X-Y)}]=E[e^{itX}e^{it(-Y)}]=E[e^{itX}]E[e^{it(-Y)}]=\phi_{X}(t)\phi_{-Y}(t)=\phi_{X}(t)\phi_{Y}(-t)=\phi_{X}(t)\phi_{X}(-t)=|\phi_X(t)|^2$$ where $\phi(t)$ is a characteristic function.Does it make sense?

Answer (score 3):

Almost: you are forgetting that $\phi$ is complex-valued.

$$\phi_X(t) \phi_{Y}(-t)=\phi_X(t) \overline{\phi_Y(t)}=\phi_X(t) \overline{\phi_X(t)} = |\phi_X(t)|^2.$$